# React Native stuck at 'Resolve dependencies'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to run a React-Native android app using `react-native run-android`, but it's stuck at

> <=------------> 12% EXECUTING [8m 44s]
>
> > :app:preDebugBuild > Resolve dependencies :app:debugRuntimeClasspath > android-job-v1.1.12a-SNAPSHOT.pom

where `android-job-v1.1.12a` is a branch in my public repo on GitHub. It seems to get stuck only for some of the branches but not all. For instance, `master-SNAPSHOT` is fine.

The repositories and dependencies sections of my build.gradle looks like this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    implementation 'com.github.myuser:android-job:v1.1.12a-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Does anyone know why it gets stuck?

EDIT:

I'm using gradle 4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out it was jitpack not building the branch correctly.

Comment: Could you share how you fixed the issue?

Answer (score 0):

hmm what gradle version are you using? have you tried to replace compile with implementation (for 3.x gradle) and implementation with compile (for 2.x gradle)

Comment: I'm using 4.1. I've tried replacing compile with implementation (for 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+') but it's the same.

Comment: and what about your repository, are you entirely sure that it is spelled correctly and that branch exist? as it sounds a bit odd that it works with master-snapshot yet it doesnt workw ith some tagged version. I can assume that there is branch called v1.1.12a (as snapshot means last commit on that branch), and repository is called android-job/

Comment: Actually I think it might be because jitpack not building the branch. I keep getting a spinning circle for v1.1.12a on jitpack.

Comment: Fixed it now. It was jitpack not building the branch properly.